# How to get lists with specific words?

Tags: python

I am learning python and I am very new to it. I have text sentences. Each text sentences have been put in a list. I want to get lists with specific words in it. I have used the following code

```
texts = emails_body_text

for line in texts:
    if "Qatar=" in lines:
        print (lines)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and be more specific about what the problem is. In the current form, it isn't clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to run the if test for each line.
Try this:

```
for line in lines:
    if "Quatar=" in line:
        print(line)
```